# tigervnc not able to connect to the server

Tags: 14.04, vnc, tightvncserver

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 and I was using remote access to connect to it from another computer, but today remote connection has stopped working and when I try to connect through tigerVNC using the server IP, I keep getting this error `Unable to connect to socket: connection refused(61)`. Would someone please help me how to activate the server for tigervnc of if there the other issue I might need to resolve first? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience with the Ubuntu 18.04 repo's official package for TigerVNC. After wasting a lot of time trying to get it to work, I finally gave up and just installed the generic Linux binaries available on the TigerVNC release page (a tarball whose contents are easily unarchived to the appropriate places in your filesystem). The release page is here: https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/releases. This is a gist describing how I did it:

https://gist.github.com/plembo/87a429f3bd1f95d4ec59b2ce8ce0a04d

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.